# How references are handled in memory

Tags: c++

```
class B {
};

class A {
    A(B& b):_b(b)  
    B& _b;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a(b);
    char* x = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
}
```

I'm creating a hash function based on the byte values of the objects. I want to know wether the bytes of object a will hold b or will they hold a reference (pointer)?

Comment: See [this list of recommended books on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056).

Comment: Objects don't have byte values. Two different byte arrays may well represent the same object value. How references are represented is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declared `A::_b` as a reference, it will "hold" a reference. Thus the object `a` does not contain the data of `b` if you examine `a` byte-wise.

---

By the way you forgot to use the address-of operator in your cast.

Comment: ... however, any access to `_b` (by name) will be as if you were accessing the referent, so this may not matter for a hash function.

Comment: and for the same refered b object, the bytes of A will always be the same?

Comment: @mkmostafa That depends on how references are implemented by the compiler.

Comment: ok. so it's not safe to hash based on the bytes if you have references. Since you might end up with two different hashes for two objects holding the same references?

Comment: @mkmostafa Thats correct. Pointers are guaranteed to work though, but then you would be hashing the pointer and not the data it points to.

Comment: yea I was looking for some way to generically hash objects and that was the  best that I could come up with so far (without using any external libs) :)